# Display index on select hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm trying to display the index of the `<option>` element in a select. However, it will not alert the selected index. How would I alert the index of the `<option>` element I am hovering over?

```
$("#sel").hover(function (e)
    {
        var $target = $(e.target);          
        if ($target.is('option'))
        {
            var selectedindex = $(this).parent().prop('selectedIndex');
            if (selectedindex != 0)
            {
                alert(selectedindex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Doesn't seem to be recognizing if it is an option

http://jsfiddle.net/poppypoop/TFDMr/1/

Comment: Mouse events don't really trigger on options, and when targeting the select it doesn't fire when you change from one option to another one etc. so this is pretty much futile. Why would you need this ?

Comment: You would have to do something like remake your select box as multiple divs instead of a select box, then you can alert when your mouse goes over the div or li whatever you use

Comment: I had originally planned to have a little description div appear next to the option the user hovers over, so they know what they're clicking. But <select> is insufficient in accomplishing this? Better to stick with li elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
var index = $(this).find("option:selected").index("option");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFDMr/2/